# Why was this question closed/deleted for lacking context?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, close-reasons, closed-questions

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4881308/proving-a-number-is-prime/4881371) was closed, and the reason was lack of [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/).

While I understand that an attempt doesn't equal context, I am confused as to what exactly was wrong with the post. The OP had made some nontrivial progress. I don't think the question was closed due to lack of source, so there may be some other reason. Maybe clarity was an issue, but it was clear to me.

The only valid reason I can think of is the OP does not provide the source, their motivation, or in what context the problem arose. But many questions have the same flaws, yet do not face such stringent actions.

Can anyone explain what exactly was lacking, and how it could have been improved?

Comment: Question was also deleted. Now, undeleted.

Comment: @GerryMyerson any insights on the close reasons?

Comment: No. Maybe one of the questions listed here under Related would help.

Comment: Reopened.......

Comment: If I remember correctly, a mod was also involved in the closing.

Comment: @DS Moderators are allowed to voice their opinion to close a question like regular users as long as there is 4 close votes on a question. This was the situation here.

Comment: @Jakobian I am aware. I thought that moderators are usually knowledgeable about the site's rules, so they may be able to point out why was it closed.

Comment: @DS They certainly are, but why a question should be closed is a choice of community.

Comment: @Jak, moderators are allowed to close questions whenever they see fit, regardless of the number of close votes previously registered. (I note that there are currently three votes to close the question again.)

Comment: There's no hard and fast rule. It depends on the people's mood.

Comment: The question didn't write “I think the following is right, can we prove it”, it merely said “prove this.” That's typical for questions someone else posed to you, e.g. exercises from some book or course. In that case, knowing about the book or course can help responders find an explanation suitable to the background of that question. So if I had to guess, I'd say yes, lack of source might have been the most likely reason for closure. But I wasn't involved, therefore this is just a guess.

Comment: count your blessings; it's much worse in physics stax.

Comment: I usually argue against closing questions for lack of context, but honestly this one does just read as a homework question.